# Specifying a mixed model with a repeated measurements factor and a random interaction factor in lmer vs. lme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Please help me understand how to write R code for a common experimental design in my field.  The exact statistical model is in the Stats Analysis paragraph below:.

> **Statistical Analyses**
>
> We used repeated measures analysis of variance (ANOVA) in SAS v.
>   9.2 (SAS Institute, Inc., Cary, NC, USA) with the mixed models procedure
>   to determine the effects of intermediate-termrest from grazing on plant
>   community characteristics. Year was the repeated variable, treatment
>   was considered a fixed variable, and block and block by treatment interactions were treated as random variables in analyses.

1. Since this is a linear mixed-effect model, would I use `lmer` (`lme4` library) or `lme` (`nlme` library)?
2. Would this be the way to write it using `lmer`?

   ```
   fm1 = lmer(PG ~ Trt + Year + (1 | Block) + (1|Block:Trt), RK_data, 
              REML = FALSE)
   ```

   Does the `(1|Block:Trt)` properly represent the block by treatment interactions as a random variable?
3. What would be the proper way to write the model using `lme`?  How would I write the block by treatment interaction as a random variable using `lme`? Below is what I started:

   ```
   fm1 = lme(PG ~ Trt+Year, random= ~ 1|Block, data=RK_data)
   ```

Comment: Could you give more details about the study design? Or a link to the paper?

Comment: @MarkWhite, here is a link to the paper: [link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rama.2016.01.002) and [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S155074241600004X).